# Is there any disadvantage to promoting early?

Tags: disgaea-4-a-promise-revisited

In *Disgaea 4 - A Promise Revisited* there seems to be a new feature which I didn't see in the original version of the game on the PS3 which is to promote a custom character up to the next unlocked tier of their class.

I keep reading that in previous games it's a bad idea to reincarnate early because you'll lose all the mana the character has in surplus. You could also lose skills if they don't have enough experience and the cost for reincarnation inflates with each use. In those games the only way to get a custom character up to a higher tier of their class was to reincarnate.

I am wondering if there are any disadvantages to using this new Promote feature the moment the next tier of a class is made available as opposed to Reincarnating a character at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

During the main game, promoting your units may be better since it would require less re-leveling, as they retain their level (instead of having it reset to 1). Reincarnation is better overall, but costs more mana, so it really isn't worth it until post-main-game.

[This post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/723483-disgaea-4-a-promise-revisited/69907435) may explain it a little better:

> You get to keep your levels as-is, almost as if that character had been of that tier all along. In addition, full reincarnation costs cumulative amounts of mana (more each time) and the rest of your mana is basically wasted. Promotion costs mana, but doesn't discard any additional mana you have.
>
> It also doesn't slightly decrease the levels of your skills, which frequent reincarnating does.

To summarize, *no*, promoting does not have any real disadvantages. It is advantageous during the main game before you are attempting the Carnage Dimension or Ba'al.